# form with target=blank redirects to new page, only after reloading the same page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms

I have a form with target="_blank" and redirects to url in new tab after submit.
But the problem is current page is fully reloaded and then redirected to the new page. 
I'm not able to figure out where i'm wrong.

```js
function postToUrl(path, params, method) {
    //alert("This will take you to bill desk for payment. After payment bill desk will return you back to the portal.");
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "msg");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "msg");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

This is the javascript function I use to submit.
What I do is, I call this javascript function in codebehind of button click event and pass the parameters.

What could be a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the javascript from the codebehind buttonclick event you **will** get a reload of the page. What you can do instead is to call the javascript directly from the button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="postToUrl(...);return false;" />
```